# MKMapView not filling view (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview

I am creating a view programmatically. The view is fairly simple as it only contains an `MKMapView` which I want to fill the screen (with the exception of the navigation bar at the top).

Here is what I am doing to setup the MKMapView:

```
- (void)setupMapView
{
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}
```

However, the `MKMapView` doesn't seem to fill the entire screen. If you look at the top of this screenshot there is a gap between the top of the map and the bottom of the navigation bar (which is added by the `UINavigationController`).

[image]

Please could someone suggest why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: At what point `setupMapView` is being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frame of the view (`self.view.frame`) probably have an offset in the `y` position. This is to position it correctly in its superviews coordinate space. When you copy that frame onto your new view it is inappropriate because you are moving into a different coordinate space.

A cheap alternative that will work in 99.9% or cases is to use the view `bounds` instead:

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Because this usually has an `origin` of zero and the full `size` of the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot - completely forgot that there may be an offset!